# ExtJS: return total rows/records in json store

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, combobox

I have a json store that returns values in json format. Now I need to get the number of rows/records in the json string but when I use `store.getCount()` function it returns 0, but the combobox is populated with rows, and when I use `store.length` I get undefined, probably because its not an array anymore, its returning from store, which is calling php script. Anyways, whats the best approach for this problem?

Comment: its an object, i tried .length and it didn't work

Comment: How is your JsonStore getting loaded (proxy, store.loadData, inline data)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var myStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.JsonStore, {
  ... config...,
  count : 0,
  listeners : {
    load : function(){
      this.count = this.getCount();
  }
}

Ext.reg('myStore', myStore);
```

and then use inside panels:

```
items : [{
 xtype : 'myStore',
 id : 'myStoreId'
}]
```

Whenever you need to get the count then you can simply do this:

```
Ext.getCmp('myStoreId').count
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Json response from server, can be something like this...

```
{
    "total": 9999,
    "success": true,
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Foo",
            "email": "foo@bar.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can use `reader: {
    type : 'json',
    root : 'users',
    totalProperty  : 'total',
    successProperty: 'success'
}` in your store object.

Answer (score 3):

As from [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getTotalCount) if your data source provided you can call `getTotalCount` to get dataset size.

Answer (score 3):

If you use ajax proxy for the store, smth like

```
proxy : {
   type : 'ajax',
   url : 'YOUR URL',
   reader : {
       type : 'json',
       root : 'NAME OF YOUR ROOT ELEMENT',
       totalProperty : 'NAME OF YOUR TOTAL PROPERTY' // requiered for paging
   }
}
```

and then load your store like
store.load(); 
There will be sent Ajax asynchronous request, so you should check count in callback like this

```
store.load({
  callback : function(records, operation, success) {
       console.log(this.getCount());         // count considering paging
       console.log(this.getTotalCount());    // total size
         // or even 
       console.log(records.length);          // number of returned records = getCount()
  }
});
```